# How to read out a capacitive sensor, (CDC, CVC, TDC)?

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, capacitive

What are the main principles for reading out a capacitive sensor? I read a lot, but I cant figure out what re the different options.

I think that an option is to convert the capacitance into a measurable voltage and the digitalise the voltage value. But what circuits or measurment principles are used as capacitance to voltage converter?

Then there is the option to integrate the capacitance into an oszillator circuit and to detect the frequency which is already done digitally. Is there also another principle to digitalize the capacitive value?

Is it possible to put these methods into categories?

Thanks a lot.